# How can i use cut and sed in awk?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, sh

First of all 
I'm new here and i want to know how can i use **cut** and **sed** in **awk** of any method to edit my test data for keep that data to array

This is my sample data:

```
isdat    pts/0        10.80.24.3       Fri Sep 20 10:20:30 2019 - Fri Sep 20 11:55:51 2019  (01:35)
```

normally i can choose usage_time by `awk '{print $15}'` it's gonna be like this
output : **(01:35)**

and i will cut by `cut -d ':' -f1 | sed -e 's/(/ /'` for hour 
and this for minute `cut -d ':' -f2 | sed -e 's/)/ /'`

But cut and sed can't use in **awk** how can i solve this problem

Comment: Don't use it _in_ awk, use it after. `awk ... | cut ... | sed ..`

Comment: @KamilCuk This is my full sample data https://pastebin.com/9tfsScb3 it hard to use after like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use them. Awk is perfectly capable of handling that on its own:

```
$ awk '
$2~/^pts/ {                     # the grep part
    split($15,a,/:/)            # split $15 by :
    for(i in a)                 # process all parts (2)
        gsub(/[()]/,"",a[i])    # remove parentheses
    print a[1],a[2]             # output both parts
}' file
```

Output:

```
01 35
```

Comment: And for that other sample in the comments, you should use `$NF` instead of `$15`.

Comment: I added "grep part" to the answer, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fine answer from James. Another slight twist using the last field (e.g. `$NF`) can be:

```
awk '{sub(/:/," ",$NF); print substr($NF,2,length($NF)-2)}' file
```

Where you simply replace the `':'` with `' '` and then take the substring between `(..)`.

**Result**

Piping your input to the expression above (and removing `file`) results in:

```
01 35
```

There is always more than one way to *skin-the-cat* with `awk`.

Per the comment, if you do want to limit output only to when the 2nd field begins with  `pts`, then you can do:

```
awk '$2~/^pts/{sub(/:/," ",$NF); print substr($NF,2,length($NF)-2)}' file
```

No magic.

Comment: in awk i can use length(var_name) for get array length too. right ?

Comment: The straight-forward answer for `awk` is No. But GNU `awk` does allow the use of `length()` with arrays -- see [String Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions)